# call proc of another language in TCL if that proc is not found in TCL

Tags: tcl

Looking out for a perl's autoload equivalent in TCL. In autoload function, will try to check if in my perl library the function name is available and take action accordingly.

According to my understanding the perl Autoload functionality: If a particular function call is not finding the function, the interpreter should call the autoload function. When we write this autoload function code, this code gets executed

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking:

1. Tcl has [`auto_mkindex`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/library.htm) where you can create an index file of your Tcl libraries, and procedures can be invoked in your application without explicitly [`package require`](http://wiki.tcl.tk/9859)-ing the libraries.
2. Tcl has the [`unknown`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/unknown.htm) procedure that will be invoked upon "proc not found". [See the wiki page](http://wiki.tcl.tk/795) for examples.